Understanding mathematics of heuristic-based outlier detection: concerns about scoring, weighting, and validity
I am trying to understand the mathematics and methodology behind a newly published outlier detection algorithm in the Computer & Security journal. This algorithm uses heuristic-based approaches, combining density- and distance-based scoring with empirical weights.
Unsupervised outlier detection (OD) algorithms often involve:

Outlier Scoring: Assigning an "outlier score" with a contamination rate (e.g., contamination=0.05) as a hyperparameter to decide thresholds.
Geometry-Based Approaches: Using dimensionality reduction techniques (e.g., PCA, LDA) to project data for better separation of classes (e.g., Matrix profile, Matrix factorization)

After they used the kernel height estimation function (KHE) (!) and some steps with unclear Math I summarized GitHub issue, finally, the new algorithm proposes a scoring formula (Equation #18):
$$
 E(O, W)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(s_i \cdot s_{c i} \cdot \omega_i\right)^3
 $$
where $s_i$, $s_{c i}$, and $\omega_i$ are score components and weights. The authors set weights $\omega_{density}=0.8$ and $\omega_{distance}=0.2$ empirically (Equation #15).

My Questions:
Mathematical Validity of Scoring and Weighting:

Does it make sense to combine outlier scores, confidence scores, and weights as shown in Equation #18?
Can a cubic transformation of combined scores improve detection accuracy, or does it introduce unnecessary bias?

Human Factor in Weighting:

The authors empirically set weights ($\omega_{density}=0.8$ and $\omega_{distance}=0.2$) for better accuracy. However, doesn’t this manual parameter tuning undermine the unsupervised nature of OD algorithms?

How can these weights be justified without clear statistical or experimental reasoning?



Additional Notes:

I’ve raised a GitHub issue in the pyod repository, summarizing the paper’s approach and questions for further discussion.
The impact of the proposed method is visualized in Figure#4 of the paper (available here GitHub issue), showing results under different scoring mixes. However, it’s unclear if these results generalize beyond the presented dataset.


Side References:

Handbook of Anomaly Detection by Chris Kuo: Discusses scoring and contamination rates in unsupervised anomaly detection.
How to test unsupervised learning methods for anomaly detection?
Confidence interval based anomaly detection


a short note about "kernel height estimation function (KHE)": Never heard about it., I'm familiar with kernel density estimators (KDE) and its implementation in Python i.e, In this Repo, I assume that the author inspired by The construction of HBOS see figure#1 tried to similarly calculate univariate $outlier_{score}=1/bins_{hight}$. Please let me know if my concerns are valid to not fully understand this new unsupervised heuristic OD algorithm and possible innovation!

what is this $F(X_{i}\mid M_{i}):=F(\begin{array}{c}{{\chi_{i}^{J,\mid c}\mid M_{f\mid c,y}^{\omega}}}\end{array})=K H E(\chi_{i}^{J,\mid c},h i s t(c\mid{\mathcal M}_{f\mid c,y}^{\omega}))?$
